# Use wildcards in npm run task for tslint so files and subfolders are linted

Tags: node.js, npm, tslint

I am using the `npm` scripts property / object to validate / lint my TypeScript files in my Angular2 project, you can see my `npm run tslint` task below:

```
"scripts": {
    "tslint" : "tslint -c tslint.json app/src/**/*.ts -e app/src/**/*.spec.ts",
  },
```

This all seems good as it is linting my actual app files, but not my tests (I will remove this later). However my real problem is that my `main.ts` file which is in the `app/src/` folder and not one of the many subfolders `app/src/*sub-folder*` is not being included in the linting. How can I improve the  wildcard above or tslint command to include typescript files in my `app/src` folder as well as those in any other subfolder?

If I haven't made myself clear please say so and I'll re-phrase the question.

Many thanks

Comment: Does it lint your `main.ts` when you remove `-e app/src/**/*spec.ts` from your script?

Comment: No, but it does lint the tests

Comment: Try to run `tslint -c tslint.json app/src/main.ts` (which will obviously just run the main.ts). Should this fail, maybe `main.ts` is not in the right directory?

Comment: I changed the command like so and it seems to be okay `tslint -c tslint.json app/src/{,**/}*.ts -e app/src/**/*.spec.ts`